# Bootstrap carousel next and prev button scroll up background page in bootstrap model

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using **Bootstrap** carousel in bootstrap model. When I click on *next* and *prev* button of **Bootstrap** carousel background page scroll up every time.

Background page should not scroll up/down while click on next and prev button of carousel. How could I fix it?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Background page should not scroll up/down while click on next and prev button of carousel.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is caused by the fluctuating heights of items within your carousel. You can prevent this be applying a fixed height to your items or the carousel as a whole.

Within the Bootstrap carousel example, they have applied a height of 500px to the .carousel element.

```
.carousel
{
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but other API js is causing the issue.So i resolved it.